# Running pre-process and inference on different instances in AWS SageMaker

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, amazon-sagemaker, inference

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to run a pre-process and inference on different instances in Sagemaker. Right now, I have an image model deployed that runs on a GPU instance, and my idea is to separate preprocessing from inference and have it on a cheaper CPU instance to (hopefully) save costs.

I tried following [multiple models with different containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/multi-container-endpoints.html) tutorial, but it looks like both jobs are running on the same instance.

Does anyone know the way to run preprocess and inference within one endpoint, but on two different instances? Or perhaps knows a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Today, the only way to have heterogeneous instance types on a single SageMaker endpoint is if you use different production variants. You would have to orchestrate which variant you send the request to yourself.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-ab-testing.html#model-testing-target-variant

Answer (score 0):

What you could do:

1. If you need batch inference, you could use [SageMaker Training Heterogeneous clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/train-heterogeneous-cluster.html) for inference (instead of training).
2. Create a pipeline where you have preprocessing in EC2, then forward the result to a SageMaker endpoint.
3. There are many of ML GPU instance types available in SageMaker, pick one that has the right mix of CPU-GPU power (e.g., G5 series). And implement internal queuing inside the instance to buffer between the pre-processing and the GPU computation.